# Installing gifify on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

So gifify is a pretty awesome script that converts videos to gifs via command line: https://github.com/vvo/gifify

I'm keen to get this working on my Windows 10 machine. I'm pretty new to windows and relatively new to coding, but I was able to get a few things working, but ran into a problem.

Here is what I did:

1. Installed node.js + npm
2. Installed FFmpeg using npm
3. Installed ImageMagick using npm (i think i did this wrong, might have only installed the wrapper).
4. Downloaded giflossy. It needed to be built (?)
5. Installed Visual Studio 2015, tried to build it using nmake and got this error:

> ```
> NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'win32cfg.h'
> ```

The command I used was:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin> .\nmake -f "C:\Users\Robert's Workstation\.npm-global\node_modules\giflossy-lossy-1.82.1\src\Makefile.w32"
```

Would really appreciate some help with this :D

Comment: Ahh posted the wrong link. This is it: https://github.com/vvo/gifify

Answer (score 1):

I think I f***ing did it!

I spent two hours wildly downloading binaries, googling like crazy and adding a quantum tonne of environment variables to the PATH, but I did it. Here's how:

- **ffmpeg**: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/. Download the binaries, place them in your Programs folder (or anywhere), copy the path and add it to your PATH environment variable
- **Gifsickle with lossy**. I tried to compile the source from GitHub, but both makefiles threw an error (I did not investigate that any further). Instead, I searched for an already compiled binary on the web (risky) and found: https://encode.ru/threads/2481-How-to-compile-giflossy. You need 7zip to extract the binaries, but once you've done this, place them in your Programs Folder, add the path to the binaries to your PATH environment variable and you're set.
- **ImageMagick** with convert: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows
  Make sure to check the following options:
  [image]

  This should add the ImageMagick binaries to the PATH env vars for you.

Battle any '[x] is not recognised as blah' errors with locating the binary and adding its path to the PATH env variable.

If there's only the source available and you have to compile it by yourself, search for compiled binaries online.

Comment: Note that if you're happy with creating basic animated gifs, you could just use ffmpeg. Here's a nice article: https://davidwalsh.name/convert-video-gif